# Python 3.5 Selenium Webdriver Chrome

Tags: python, windows, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I got selenium work with Firefox and IE but I can't get work with Chrome yet :S

this is my code (simple just to check):

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

The problem is that Chrome open the window but after get stuck, doesn't neither go to the webpage and I receive this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Carlo/Desktop/CEx/src/IE.py", line 21, in 
>       driver.get('https://www.google.com')   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 248, in get
>       self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 234, in execute
>       response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)   File
>   "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 407, in execute
>       return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 439, in _request
>       resp = self._conn.getresponse()   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1197, in getresponse
>       response.begin()   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 297, in begin
>       version, status, reason = self._read_status()   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 258, in _read_status
>       line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\socket.py", line 575, in readinto
>       return self._sock.recv_into(b) ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

The problem is that I don't have any other connection open :S and when it open the chrome window on the top of the page I receive this:

> You are using an unsupported command-line flag:
>   --ignore-certificate-errors. Stability and security will suffer.

I really believe that this is causing the not working of selenium but I'm not getting it right! some help pls?!?!?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use following code and let me know in case of any issues:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("test-type")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```